# Как вывести перед каждой строкой дополнительную строку?

Tags: c, строки, вывод

Есть файл в котором хранится информация о дистрибутиве. Я читаю данный файл и сохраняю в небольшой буфер. Выглядит это так:

```
char tmpf_buffer[124];
nb = read(fd, tmpf_buffer, sizeof(tmpf_buffer));
/* Внутри -> Manjaro Linux\n20.0.30\nLysia\n */
```

После вывода содержимого в `stdout` получаю такую информацию:

```
Manjaro Linux
20.0.3
Lysia
```

Как перед каждой строкой вывести другую строку?

Например:

```
Название: Manjaro Linux
Релиз: 20.0.3
Кодовое слово: Lysia
```

Пробовал использовать высокоуровневые конструкции ввода-вывода, файловый дескриптор конвертировал в файловый поток, читал файл с помощью `fgets`, например так:

```
tmpf_stream = fdopen(fd, "r");
char *col_names[] = {"Название:", "Релиз:", "Кодовое слов:"};
while (fgets(tmpf_buffer, sizeof(tmpf_buffer), tmpf_stream)) {
  printf("%s %s", col_names[index++], tmpf_buffer);
```

И тогда вывод будет правильным, но это решение не подходит для моей программы, ибо вывод информации осуществляет отдельная функция. Подходит решение с `read`, сохраняю информацию в буфер с `\n`, а затем в конце другой программы осуществляю `printf`. Но как вывести данный буфер с дополнительной информацией?

Еще пытался сделать таким образом:

```
char *col_names[] = {"Название дистрибутива:", "Релиз:", "Кодовое название:"};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 printf("%s %s\n", col_names[i], tmpf_buffer);
}
```

Но в выводе будет:

```
Название дистрибутива: Manjaro Linux
20.0.3
Lysia

Релиз: Manjaro Linux
20.0.3
Lysia

Кодовое название: Manjaro Linux
20.0.3
Lysia
```

Как этого избежать?

Comment: Ну разбирайте считанное в буфер на строки и предваряйте вывод нужными строками, в чем проблема?...

Comment: @Harry, вы имеете ввиду сделать перебор tmpf_buffer? я так уже делал, у меня выводятся одни символы, а не строки. Или имелось ввиду создать отдельный буфер и в него дозаписывать? И сделать как бы указатель на строку?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2328182/13970074

Comment: У Вас ошибка (опечатка?) в первой строке: "char *tmpf_buffer[124];" Звёздочка здесь явно лишняя...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, например, навскидку - так:

```
void out(const char * buf)
{
    const char *col_names[] = {
        "Название дистрибутива:",
        "Релиз:", "Кодовое название:"
    };
    for(int pre = 1, i = 0; *buf; buf++)
    {
        if (pre) { printf("%s ",col_names[i++]); pre = 0; }
        if (*buf == '\n') pre = 1;
        putchar(*buf);
    }
}

int main()
{
    out("Manjaro Linux\n20.0.30\nLysia\n");
}
```

Как видите, в `out` передается весь буфер. Можно воспользоваться `strtok`, но содержимое буфера при этом меняется...

Comment: логику понял, спасибо